# Rewriting a small C-define into "normal" C++ function

Tags: c++, c, function

I have found this piece of code and **"*carved it out*"** from `<X11/Xutil.h>`:

```c
#define XGetPixel(ximage, x, y) \
    ((*((ximage)->f.get_pixel))((ximage), (x), (y)))
```

I would like to re-write it into a *normal function*, but I don't know how. Can anyone assist?

For clarification:

- What I want to achieve here, when that small piece of code is working in C++ too as it is?

  I would like to understand what it is, and how to re-write it myself in the future.
- What I am using it for?

  Single pixel color RGB extraction.
- How long am I coding in C++ and in what environment?

  I am a shell scripter more than C++ coder on Linux (Mint 19), `g++-8`, in total have spent about one half a year in C++ only.
- Why don't I simply `#include <X11/Xutil.h>`?

  I just don't think I need it, better stick with X11/Xlib.h I believe, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What types are ximage, x and y?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XGetPixel.html) helps

Comment: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XGetPixel.html says it's a function

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak What do you mean, what is its purpose? Its purpose is to get pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation calls this a function](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XGetPixel.html); possibly they've made it a macro instead for "performance" and considered it to be an as-if implementation; I wouldn't have but okay.

But this means the documentation tells you the argument types and return type, which is all you need to know.

```
unsigned long XGetPixel(ximage, x, y)
      XImage *ximage;
      int x;
      int y;
```

You already know the implementation:

```
((*((ximage)->f.get_pixel))((ximage), (x), (y)))
```

So, and removing some now-redundant parens:

```
unsigned long XGetPixel(XImage* ximage, int x, int y)
{
    return (*ximage->f.get_pixel)(ximage, x, y);
}
```

Be careful that this doesn't conflict with the macro, which it will be prone to do due to how macros are unscoped.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing types, you might do something like:

```
template <typename Image, typename X typename Y>
auto XGetPixel(Image&& ximage, X&& x, Y&& y)
-> decltype((*(std::forward<Image>(ximage)->f.get_pixel))(std::forward<Image>(ximage),
                                                         std::forward<X>(x),
                                                         std::forward<Y>(y)))
{
    return (*(std::forward<Image>(ximage)->f.get_pixel))(std::forward<Image>(ximage),
                                                         std::forward<X>(x),
                                                         std::forward<Y>(y));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 answer `inline`, and add `const`

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
#define INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#else
#define INLINE inline
#endif 

INLINE unsigned long XGetPixel(XImage* ximage, const int x, const int y)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: [Advantages of inline in C++ (or C)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/)

Comment: so remove from there.

Comment: copy-pasted your define code, and vscode grayed out the latter part, so I should probably use `inline __attribute__((always_inline))`... :-| getting tired, but thank you, I did not benchmark it yet, but I believe you did the inline for speed, right?

Comment: yes. I afraid VS code will not understand it correctly as those macros are evaluated during the compilations